# jQuery Autocomplete without right values

Tags: jquery

When I try the autocomplete works but not with the words mentioned in an array called `liste`. Only on the last written words in the browser. Any ideas about that?

```js
var liste = [
  "Draggable",
  "Droppable",
  "Resizable",
  "Selectable",
  "Sortable"
];

$('#recherche').autocomplete({
  source: liste
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward, can u kindly try with latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI, also check if JS is enabled in ur browser.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be working fine.

```js
var liste = [
  "Draggable",
  "Droppable",
  "Resizable",
  "Selectable",
  "Sortable"
];

$('#recherche').autocomplete({
  source: liste
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="recherche" value="" />
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit in the comment section?

Comment: This is completely unbelievable.... It doesn't work on my computer. My browser is Google Chrome. Did you try the same lines of code? Thank you for your help (I don't know why you got a -1....)

Comment: @luciferous yes, it should have been in comments. I was just trying to run the code in code snippet, and it ran so I submitted it as answer to show it working.

Comment: @Kuartz Yes, I used exactly your code. I just added an input box to make it a working demo.

Comment: OK... It work with "Run code snippet". So I think I have to clear the memory cache of my browser and try again. Thank you very much.